# alter ng-repeat order of graph presentation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to alter my graphs disposal and I have this

```
{"Modem_Signal_lte0":{"data":[["2017-08-03T07:55:35.000Z",53.1],["2017-08-03T08:00:35.000Z",52.58],["2017-08-03T08:05:35.000Z",52.83],["2017-08-03T08:10:35.000Z",53],["2017-08-03T08:15:35.000Z",53],["2017-08-03T08:20:35.000Z",53],["2017-08-03T08:25:35.000Z",53],["2017-08-03T08:30:35.000Z",54.42],["2017-08-03T08:35:35.000Z",53.05],["2017-08-03T08:40:35.000Z",54.78],["2017-08-03T08:45:35.000Z",55.43],["2017-08-03T08:50:35.000Z",58.55]],"options":{"labels":["Date","rssi"],"showRangeSelector":true,"legend":"always","ylabel":"dBm","title":"Modem Signal","axes":{"y":{}},"width":{}}},"Modem_Roaming_lte0":{"data":[["2017-08-03T07:56:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:01:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:06:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:11:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:16:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:21:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:26:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:31:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:36:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:41:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:46:45.000Z",0],["2017-08-03T08:51:45.000Z",0]],"options":{"labels":["Date","roaming"],"showRangeSelector":true,"legend":"always","ylabel":"","title":"Modem Roaming","axes":{"y":{}},"width":{}}},"Modem_Activity_lte0":{"data":[["2017-08-03T07:55:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:00:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:05:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:10:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:15:35.000Z",0.98],["2017-08-03T08:20:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:25:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:30:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:35:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:40:35.000Z",0.98],["2017-08-03T08:45:35.000Z",1],["2017-08-03T08:50:35.000Z",0.98]],"options":{"labels":["Date","state"],"showRangeSelector":true,"legend":"always","ylabel":"","title":"Modem Activity","axes":{"y":{}},"width":{}}},"Modem_Mode_lte0":{"data":[["2017-08-03T07:55:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:00:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:05:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:10:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:15:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:20:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:25:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:30:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:35:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:40:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:45:35.000Z",6],["2017-08-03T08:50:35.000Z",6]],"options":{"labels":["Date","Sysmode"],"showRangeSelector":true,"legend":"always","ylabel":"","title":"Modem Mode","axes":{"y":{"includeZero":true}},"width":{}}}}
```

And then it presents four graphs "Modem Activity", "Modem Mode", "Modem Roaming" and "Modem Signal".

I need to switch the graph "Modem Roaming" with "Modem Signal".

How to do this?

My view:

```
<tab heading="Modems" select="changeTab()" disable="!tabClick" active="activeTab.modem">
    <div class="no-data" ng-if="activeNoData.modem">
         <img src="/assets/img/nodata.png"/>
         <h3>No Data</h3>
    </div>
    <tabset class="box-tab box-tab-sub"> 
         <tab ng-repeat="type in dataGraph.modem.types" heading="{{type.label}}" select="changeSubTab(type.type)" disable="!tabClick">
            <p>{{dataGraph.modem[type.type]}}</p>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:30px" ng-repeat="graph in dataGraph.modem[type.type]">
                <img ng-if="!graph.options" style="height:32px;margin:50px auto;" src="/assets/img/loader.gif" />
                <div ng-if="graph.options">
                    <dygraph options='graph.options' data="graph.data"></dygraph><br>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </tab>
    </tabset>
</tab>
```

Comment: what do you meant by:  switch the graph "Modem Roaming" with "Modem Signal"?

Comment: Yes... the order in my browser seems asc i dont know if its true... but i know we can manipulate the array for the ng-repeat and when i console-log my graph types i saw inside the first element the graph i show in last and i want to show in thrid

Comment: will key always be Modem_Signal_lte0 and Modem_Roaming_lte0 or its dyanamic?

Comment: I inject this from my databse into my types array for modems... for now is just that

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of key in an object is not guaranteed. You need to reorganize them into array if you care about the sequence.

```
var data = // data here

var dataArr = [];
dataArr.push(data.Modem_Activity_lte0);
dataArr.push(data.Modem_Mode_lte0);
dataArr.push(data.Modem_Roaming_lte0);
dataArr.push(data.Modem_Signal_lte0);
```